# XSLT - how to deal with <![CDATA[

Tags: xslt

Im trying to output some XML using XSLT, however I've just come across this:

```
<description><![CDATA[<p>Using Money &ndash; recognise coins, getting change, paper money etc. A PowerPoint resource containing colour coded levels to suit different abilities &ndash; special needs. Self checking and interactive.</p>]]></description>
```

How do I output the actual HTML, not the `<P>`, but as if it was HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`disable-output-escaping`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping). Beware, though, that if the input value is not well-formed or valid, the output won't be either.

```
<xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT handles data already parsed by the XML parser. The `CDATA` tags are parsed as text by the XML parser. You might need to do some pre-processing to remove the `CDATA` tags before turning over the XML to XSLT.